# Laravel Echo with NodeJS HTTPS doesn't work

Tags: node.js, laravel, sockets, socket.io, laravel-echo

I've been developing this NodeJS application that takes advantage of Laravel Echo's functionalities to receive information from a server through socket connection.

**Server-side**
Laravel Echo Server with Laravel 5.7.19

**Client-side**
"laravel-echo": "^1.5.2"
"socket.io": "^2.2.0"

```
import Echo from '../../node_modules/laravel-echo/dist/echo.common.js'
import Socketio from 'socket.io-client';

let echo = new Echo({ 

  broadcaster: 'socket.io',
  host: 'https://smartfish.danymota.com:8080/',
  encrypted: true,
  secure: true,
  client: Socketio,
  auth: {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token.bearerToken,
    },
  },
});
echo.private('central.' + macAddress)
  .listen('RulesUpdated', (response) => {
    handleRules(JSON.parse(response.aquarios))
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleString() + " - Rules updated")
  })
```

**Problem**
Everything works fine in Http, when I switch to HTTPS it just stops working. Also, the socket connection doesn't reach the server (or at least Laravel-echo-server doesn't log it)

**IMPORTANT - What I've tried**

1. Ran the application through Browserify, and then on the browser (**it works just fine on a browser, even with HTTPS**)
2. Played around with different ports (Again, it works with HTTP, so ports are likely not the problem)
3. Changed the URL to wss://, /socket.io
4. Forced socket.io to include a secure: true on options
5. Changed the version of Laravel Echo
6. Tried importing both echo.common.js and echo.js

**Notes**

/api/broadcasting/auth - This is working, so problem is likely not here

**Laravel echo server configuration**

```
    {
    "authHost": "https://smartfish.danymota.com",
    "authEndpoint": "/api/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [{
        "appId": "f7506b5e7118092c",
        "key": "9015d93999f3a2f7f95a054a76fbcbfd"
    }],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath1": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "8080",
    "protocol": "https",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "/home/danymota/ssl/cert/smartfish.danymota.com.crt",
    "sslKeyPath": "/home/danymota/ssl/private/smartfish.danymota.com.key",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "http://smartfishweb.test/api",
        "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

**Socket.io debug**

```
socket.io-client:url parse https://smartfish.danymota.com:8080/socket.io +0ms
socket.io-client new io instance for https://smartfish.danymota.com:8080/socket.io +0ms
socket.io-client:manager readyState closed +0ms
socket.io-client:manager opening https://smartfish.danymota.com:8080/socket.io +0ms
socket.io-client:manager connect attempt will timeout after 20000 +4ms
socket.io-client:manager readyState opening +1ms
socket.io-client:manager connect_error +60ms
socket.io-client:manager cleanup +0ms
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by adding a flag `rejectUnauthorized: false` to laravel echo.

```
  this.echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'socket.io',
  host: config.ECHO_SERVER,
  client: Socketio,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  auth: {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token.bearerToken,
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

that because you have to set laravel echo server settings

use this command `laravel-echo-server init` and choose https when setting the protocol

or open `laravel-echo-server.json`

and change protocol to https

```
{
"authHost": "https://smartfish.danymota.com:8080",
"authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
"clients": [
    {
        "appId": "It generates it from the command init",
        "key": "It generates it from the command init"
    }
],
"database": "Your database driver",
"databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {},
    "sqlite": {
        "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
},
"devMode": true,
"host": null,
"port": "6001", // your node js port the default is 6001
"protocol": "https", // change it here
"socketio": {},
"sslCertPath": "",
"sslKeyPath": "",
"sslCertChainPath": "",
"sslPassphrase": "",
"apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": true,
    "allowOrigin": "Your domain with the port",
    "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
    "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've updated the post and included my LES config file. As I said in the post, HTTPS works if I run Laravel Echo in a browser.

Comment: can you please change `authHost` from `https://smartfish.danymota.com` to `https://smartfish.danymota.com:8080` and the same for `allowOrigin` and tell me if it worked

Comment: Thanks, Just did that and nothing. Also, my auth host is not running on port 8080, so that is likely not the problem, and the auth is working in both HTTP and HTTPS (browser)

Comment: can you please tell me what's in the console of laravel echo server, when you type  `laravel-echo-server start` what do you see ? in my case 
`Running at https://website.com on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for https events...
✔  Listening for redis events.` and when i open `https://website.com:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js` it works without any problems , maybe there is a problem starting the server

Comment: Again, server is fine. It works with HTTP. And it even works with HTTPS if the app in ran on a browser. I'm currenty working with Echo in HTTP and I'm publish and subscribing to multiple channels and events just fine. Problem occurs if I run the application in CLI (nodejs server.js) and in HTTPS, if I do that, Echo server doesn't log anything at all.

Comment: in your `Socket.io debug` you are making new instance from `https://smartfish.danymota.com:8080/socket.io` can you please change it to `https://smartfish.danymota.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js`

Comment: No luck, tried that with https and with wss, but in vain... :(

Comment: after searching i found out that `Port 8080 is an alternative to port 80 and is used primarily for http traffic` that maybe the problem that the port is in use for something else , so please change the port from 8080 to 6001 and make sure it's open you can use ufw `ufw allow 6001` here is detailed information on openning ports https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-14-04 hope that works